# Vectorize jax.lax.cond with vmap

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, jax, autodiff

Hi why can't I vectorize the condition function to apply for a list of boolean? or is there something else going on here?

```
DK = jnp.array([[True],[True],[False],[True]])
f1 = lambda x: 1
f2 = lambda y: 0
cond = lambda dk: jax.lax.cond(dk,f1,f2)
vcond = jax.vmap(cond)
vcond(DK)
```

I was expecting it to give me an array.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here: first, `lax.cond` requires a scalar predicate, and you are vmapping a 2D input, which ends up effectively passing a 1D predicate. You can fix this by using two levels of `vmap`:

```py
vcond = jax.vmap(jax.vmap(cond))
```

Second, you've set up your `f1` and `f2` to take an argument `x`, but it doesn't appear you have any value `x` to pass to them (if you did, you could pass it as `jax.lax.cond(dk,f1,f2,x)`). If no `x` argument is needed, you can redefine the functions to take no arguments. The resulting code looks like this:

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax

DK = jnp.array([[True],[True],[False],[True]])
f1 = lambda: 1
f2 = lambda: 0
cond = lambda dk: jax.lax.cond(dk,f1,f2)
vcond = jax.vmap(jax.vmap(cond))
result = vcond(DK)
print(result)
# [[1]
#  [1]
#  [0]
#  [1]]
```

Note that you can avoid a lot of this complexity by replacing your code with `jnp.where`. For example:

```py
result = jnp.where(DK, 1, 0)
```

This will lower to essentially the same XLA `select` operation as your original code.

Comment: I find that `jax.nump.where`/`jax.numpy.select` (`jax.lax.select`) and `jax.numpy.piecewise` (`jax.lax.switch`) cover most reasons to use a conditional.

Sometimes these methods are substantially faster than `at[mask].set()`, other times essentially the same.

Comment: I see. Do you have a blog/tutorial where these are interchangeably used for common conditional cases?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
DK = jnp.array([[True],[True],[False],[True]])
f1 = lambda x: 1
f2 = lambda y: 0

# New_Version
cond = lambda dk: jax.lax.cond(dk, lambda x: f1(x), lambda x: f2(x), dk)
# ----------------------------^^^ check condition
# ------------------------------------------------------------------^^^ pass to f1 or f2 base the result of condition

# Old_Version
cond = lambda dk: jax.lax.cond(dk,
                               dk, lambda x: f1(x),
                               dk, lambda x: f2(x))

vcond = jax.vmap(jax.vmap(cond))
vcond(DK)
```

Output:

```
DeviceArray([[1],
             [1],
             [0],
             [1]], dtype=int32, weak_type=True)
```

Comment: `jax.lax.cond(dk,
                               dk, lambda x: f1(x),
                               dk, lambda x: f2(x))` why is there a extra dk before lambda func? the documentation for jax.lax.cond only has ( predicate,fun1,fun2). Amazingly it worked!

Comment: `jax.lax.cond(dk, x, f1, x, f2)` is an older deprecated signature for `lax.cond`, which still works but will raise a warning. The new call signature is `jax.lax.cond(dk, f1, f2, x)` where `dk` is the predicate, and `x` is the argument that will be passed to either `f1` or `f2`.

Comment: @jakevdp, thanks a lot, edited the answer and add a new version.

Comment: @Kapil, You're welcome. Thanks `jakevdp` you got the answer, also I edited the answer for the new version.